# Mobile menu appears blank, failing to change styles

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, web

At some point in developing my site, the mobile menu stopped displaying any of my navigation.

I tried to make the nav show up by changing the stylesheet e.g. color of text, z-index, background color etc but none of my changes have shown up. (see below)

I may be reading the dev tools incorrectly, missing a style that could help, or there could be something more complex afoot.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

#mobile-navigation-jquery {
  background-color:rgb(28, 34, 48)!important;
  z-index:200;
}

#menu-header,
#menu-item-49,
#menu-item-442,
#menu-item-56,
#menu-item-54,
#menu-item-51,
#menu-item-667 {
  z-index:200;
  color: black;}

}
```

Comment: Maybe it is not an stylesheet issue and it is caused by JS code.

Comment: I'm not versed in Javascript, but I rationalized that, since the theme is used widely, the core script should function. However, I changed plenty of CSS styles throughout development and may have made some over-generalized reference that is affecting the menu.

Comment: The problem was solved by a more specific selection path and changing the position to fixed (or relative):
`@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  #mobile-navigation > div > ul,
  #mobile-navigation-jquery > div > ul {
      position: fixed;
  }
  #mobile-navigation-jquery.target > div > ul {
      width: 100%;
  }`